# Overriding a behavior in a directive : Best practices?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two directives, each displaying a list of documents, but in a slightly different way : One displays user-favorited documents, and the other one displays user-pinned documents. These two properties depend on two object members specified for each document, i.e. :

```
document = {
    pinned: true,
    favorite: false
};
```

Each directive displays a frame with its own title, according to the type of documents we want to display. For refactoring purposes, I use the same template for both, and specify varying template strings and objects in two controllers, each one dedicated to a directive. (i.e. the service member to call to get the documents we want is specified in a string, since the handling of these is exactly the same)

…Until I realized the two controllers were almost identical, the only thing that changed being… template strings.

So what I came up with is using the exact same controller and template (`DocumentsPanel`), but still with two directives, the only difference in them being `link()` :

```
function documentsPanelFavorites(templateService, resources) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: templateService.getUrl('Documents/Panel/documentsPanel.html'),
        controller: 'DocumentsPanel',
        scope: true,
        link: link
    };

    function link(scope) {
        //Used to show a favorite/pinned checkmark for each document entry
        scope.documentOptions = {
            showFavoriteCheckmark: true, 
            showPinnedCherkmark: false
        };

        scope.panelName = resources.text.MODULE_TITLE_FAVORITE_DOCUMENTS;
        scope.className = 'favorites';
        scope.noDocumentText = 'No favorite for this user';

        // Used by the controller to know which method of the
        // document dataService to call to get the listed documents
        scope.documentList = 'favoriteDocuments'
        // etc.
    }
};
```

The documentsPanel.html template then uses these strings defined in the controller's scope via `link()`.

Note: Another directive used to represent a document in a list is included in `documentsPanel.html`, that's why I set both `showPinned` and `showFavorite` options in each directive : It's the same directive that displays each document, and it is used elsewhere with all settings to `true`.

Would that be considered good practice? If not, what would be a better solution?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I would expect `documents="document | filter:{pinned:true}"` and `documents="document | filter:{favorite:true}"`... Considering title, no document text, etc. I would first create config object and pass it to directive: `config.title = '...', config.nodoctext = ...` But if number of this strings params is too big, just create 2 templates.

Comment: I edited the original question, since I realized I wasn't very clear on some points : The controller's code has been edited so access to some members is defined by scope variables (i.e. to define which service member to call to get the desired documents list : They're not the same but their handling is strictly identical). the `showFavorite` and `showPinned` are also only used to show or hide checkmarks, not to set a filter.